# Why does the viewBox affect my non-scaling stroke?

Tags: svg

If you run the snippet, you will see that a viewbox that is not as tall as the non-scaled stroke makes the stroke, well, go wonky. Drag the size handle to see it grow and shrink. Aside from adjusting the viewBox, is there something that can be done to fix this?

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
}
svg {
  overflow: visible;
  width: 45%;
}

line {
  stroke: #cc0000;
  stroke-width: 10;
  vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <svg viewBox="0 0 2000 10">
    <line x2="2000" ></line>
  </svg>

  <svg viewBox="0 0 2000 500">
    <line x2="2000"></line>
  </svg>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The subpixel rounding is tricky for some browsers and this causes that flickering and ugly scaling.

The easiest way to work around the problem is to add some height to the svg itself.
This solution may be  not suitable for more complex svg (since polygons, circles and similar will be stretched, in Google Chrome at least) but works nice in this case.

```
svg { height: 100% }
```

Here the edited snippet:

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
}
svg {
  overflow: visible;
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
}

line {
  stroke: #cc0000;
  stroke-width: 10;
  vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <svg viewBox="0 0 2000 10">
    <line x2="2000" ></line>
  </svg>

  <svg viewBox="0 0 2000 500">
    <line x2="2000"></line>
  </svg>

</div>
```